# How can i restrict maximum occurrence of an element based on another element value in XML

Tags: xml, xsd, altova, xmlspy

I have an element 'ABC'.
For that element there are 3 child elements.
a,b and c and these are of type integer.
and maximum occurrence of element c is infinity.
if the value of element 'a' is 1 and 'b' is 2 then the occurrence of 'c' should be 3.
Can i set the maximum occurrence of element c dynamically. or based on the value of elements 'a' and 'b'
Eg:Refer the images [Refer the screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXDgt.jpg) [Refer the screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm5zy.jpg) [Refer the screenshot of value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KA24.jpg)

Comment: In XSD 1.1 this might be possible to check using an assertion. Do you use XSD 1.0 or 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

XSD 1.1 schema with `xs:assert`:

```
   <xs:element name="ABC">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="a" type="xs:integer"/>
                <xs:element name="b" type="xs:integer"/>
                <xs:element name="c" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert id="restrict-occurence" test="count(c) = a + b"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

That way a sample like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ABC xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="assert-example1.xsd">
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
    <c>foo</c>
    <c>bar</c>
    <c>baz</c>
</ABC>
```

is considered valid while

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ABC xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="assert-example1.xsd">
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
    <c>foo</c>
</ABC>
```

raises a validation error about the assertion failing: `Assertion evaluation ('count(c) = a + b') for element 'ABC' on schema type '#AnonType_ABC' did not succeed.`.

Tested with Xerces in oXygen, I don't have XMLSpy here to test.

Make sure you use a version that supports/has enabled XSD schema 1.1 support.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But Its not working

Comment: @ANUJIVARGHESE, I don't have XML Spy but I tested in oXygen with Xerces and Saxon and XSD 1.1 support and the sample assert seemed to do what I understood you want to achieve, I will add the samples to the answer. Explain in more detail whether you get an error, which one, or what exactly happens.

Comment: Can you please refer the screenshots attached. Its not working in altova xmlspy

Comment: @ANUJIVARGHESE, while screenshots can help please also share minimal but complete XML and XSD samples as code snippets. I guess it might be a namespace problem but it is not possible to tell without seeing minimal but complete samples as code. Can you try whether the simple example based on your original question and used in my answer also fails in Altova? This example doesn't use namespaces.

Comment: @ANUJIVARGHESE, as an alternative, of course, ask the Altova support whether they can help you with the problem.

Comment: If the schema uses a target namespace and the elements your assertion refers to are in that namespace it might be necessary to add `xpathDefaultNamespace="##targetNamespace"` to the `xs:assert` element.